# Writing dynamic SQL in SQL Server 2016 throwing error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is my stored procedure in SQL Server 2016:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [USA_PHILIPS].[usp_stock]
    @VCM INT,
    @ID VARCHAR, 
    @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [USA_PHILIPS].[stock]

    SELECT STOCKNUMBER,STOCKBOOKS
    INTO [USA_PHILIPS].[stock]
    FROM [USA_PHILIPS].[DMARTSTOCK]
    WHERE VCM = @VCM
      AND ID = @ID
END
```

How can I pass schema name as a parameter `@SCHEMA_NAME`?

And execute these statements as dynamic SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [USA_PHILIPS].[stock]
```

Please help.

Comment: maybe you can find the answer here? it's been answered a ton, and a quick google will give lots of results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505282/writing-stored-procedures-when-using-dynamic-schema-names-in-sql-server

Comment: Unrelated to your issue here, but why are you dropping and creating the table ? Why not use use `MERGE` or `INSERT` & `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally do it this way, injecting the value directing into the dynamic query. I also fix some of your data types:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [USA_PHILIPS].[usp_stock] @VCM int,
                                           @ID varchar(25), --Always define your varchar lengths
                                           @SCHEMA_NAME sysname --Correct data type for object names

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
   
    SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME) + N'.[stock];' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
               N'SELECT STOCKNUMBER,STOCKBOOKS' + @CRLF +
               N'INTO ' + QUOTEMANE(@SCHEMA_NAME) + N'.[stock]' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM [USA_PHILIPS].[DMARTSTOCK]' + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE VCM=@VCM' + @CRLF +
               N'  AND ID = @ID;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@VCM int, @ID varchar(25)', @VCM, @ID;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the code needs to be dynamic if an identifier is dynamic -- and you have to munge query strings:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [USA_PHILIPS].[usp_stock] (
    @VCM INT,
    @ID VARCHAR(255), 
    @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(50)
) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql = NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [SCHEMA].[stock]';
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[SCHEMA]', QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME));

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;

    SET @sql = '
SELECT STOCKNUMBER, STOCKBOOKS
Into [SCHEMA].[stock]
from [USA_PHILIPS].[DMARTSTOCK]
WHERE VCM=@VCM AND ID = @ID';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[SCHEMA]', QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME));

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
         N'@vcm INT, @id VARCHAR(255)',
         @vcm=@vcm, @id=@id;

END;
```

Note some important changes to the query:

- `@ID` has a length as an argument.  This is important because the default varies by context and it might (well probably isn't) long enough for what you want.
- I assume that you want the same table referenced in the `DELETE` as the `INTO`.
- Pass the constant values as parameters.